# How do I run a function when page loads up react-18

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to track user's start and end time in a page using mixpanel. To do that I want to the user's start time for a page's session and page exit or end time. To do that I need to run the function during page load.

In React 18 we cannot use the useEffect hook because it triggers twice, I only want to trigger it once to have accurate results.

Comment: for production builds useEffect will run only once.

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` hook triggers twice only in strict mode and only during development.

So if you want to monitor your user sessions in production, using a `useEffect` hook with and empty dependency array to start the timer, and its cleanup-function to stop the timer, would be the recommended way.

Comment: Sry for repling late but this is how I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that `useEffect()` in build production run only once, you can use this trick during development if you want.

First create a new component (eg. `src/components/use-effect-once/index.jsx`)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const useEffectOnce = ( effect )=> {

    const destroyFunc = useRef();
    const effectCalled = useRef(false);
    const renderAfterCalled = useRef(false);
    const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  
    if (effectCalled.current) {
        renderAfterCalled.current = true;
    }
  
    useEffect( ()=> {
  
        // only execute the effect first time around
        if (!effectCalled.current) { 
          destroyFunc.current = effect();
          effectCalled.current = true;
        }
  
        // this forces one render after the effect is run
        setVal(val => val + 1);
  
        return ()=> {
          // if the comp didn't render since the useEffect was called,
          // we know it's the dummy React cycle
          if (!renderAfterCalled.current) { return; }
          if (destroyFunc.current) { destroyFunc.current(); }
        };
    }, []);
};
```

Then import where you need it...

```
import { useEffectOnce } from 'src/components/use-effect-once';

//replace useEffect() with this:
useEffectOnce(() => {
    console.log('my effect is running');
    // do something here!
    return () => console.log('my effect is destroying');
});
```

[Source](https://dev.to/ag-grid/react-18-avoiding-use-effect-getting-called-twice-4i9e)